# How to run a bash script from crontab and send the output to desktop notifications

Tags: linux, bash, cron, cron-task, raid

I'm trying to get the RAID status every time i boot into my system (Debian) and send the output as notification in the desktop.
This works as expected from terminal:
`sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep 'Working Devices :' | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "$OUTPUT"; done`

but it won't work if I run a crontab job pointing at the script :

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep 'Working Devices :' | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "$OUTPUT"; done
```

The script is set to be executable and is ran from crontab root as:

```
@reboot /PATH/scripth.sh
```

this also won't work:

```
* * * * * /PATH/scripth.sh
```

and logs are not produced when:

```
* * * * * /PATH/scripth.sh > /PATH/crontab.log
```

Comment: Try add to your script at first string: export DISPLAY=':0.0'

Comment: Add errors out to log:

"* * * * * /PATH/scripth.sh > /PATH/crontab.log 2>&1"

and check crontab.log

Answer (score 2):

This work in my PC (change username):

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep 'Working Devices :' | while read OUTPUT; do su - RealUserName -c "DISPLAY=':0.0' notify-send \"$OUTPUT\""; done
```

Comment: You might consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.